# jquery Chosen Deselect Not Working in an Old Version

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

So I'm using v0.9.7 of the jQuery Chosen plugin. I'm kinda stuck with it because there is a whole framework at both client and server which is not compatible with the latest version. I did not write either framework and it would be a huge job figuring out how to change them. So, I'm stuck on 0.9.7

We are using an AJAX list with the Quicklist feature. My problem is, the deselect "cross" is not working. That cross is present because the field is non-mandatory.

Whenever I clear the list by clicking it, the first item in the most recent search is posted to the server.

I can't figure out how to intercept any events to tell whether the deselect cross has been clicked.

A click event handler on the *abbr* element does not work for some reason.

That version of the plugin does not send a *params* parameter to the change event for the select control, as I have seen in many SO answers (too old).

The only thing I can think of is to have a separate button, completely separate to the control to clear the hospitals list.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you find a way to reproduce the problem? The [oldest version of Chosen is 0.9.8 on CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/chosen/0.9.8)... Maybe you could create a [CodePen](https://codepen.io) with it.

Comment: world changed, develop & effort just for updated user !

Comment: Errrm. OK. Please take your hands off the keyboard now.